# Show a Java graph on HTML page on button click

Tags: javascript, java, html, swing

I have a Java class which outputs a graph on `JFrame`.

```
public class ShowGraph{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Example");
        DrawGraph dgraph = new DrawGraph();
        f.getContentPane().add(dgraph);
        f.setsize(800,600);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

public class DrawGraph extends JPanel
{
   public void renderGraph ( Graphics g ){
       super.renderGraph( g );
       Dimension size = this.getSize();
       g.translate (size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
       quadraticGraph (g, 0.5, 0, 0);

    }
   private void quadraticGraph (Graphics g, double a, double b, double c) {
       Dimension size = this.getSize();
       g.setColor (Color.red);

       int hBound = size.width / 2;
       for (int i = -hBound; i <= hBound; i++) {
           int x1 = i;
           int y1 = (int) (a * x1 * x1 + b * x1 + c);
           y1 = - y1;

           int x2 = x1 + 1;
           int y2 = (int) (a * x2 * x2 + b * x2 + c);
           y2 = - y2;

           g.drawLine (x1, y1, x2, y2);
      }

 }
```

The above code generates a quadratic graph on the frame.

I want to show this graph to the user, when the user clicks a button on HTML page.

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<button type="button">Generate Graph</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is that HTML page being served to users?  Tomcat?  GlassFish?

Comment: The HTML page is served using a Jetty server.

Comment: I'd feed the variables as URL parameters and have the HTML page draw the graph using JavaScript and the `canvas` element. There are probably APIs to draw graphs on web pages - Google is your friend there. It would be off-topic to ask for APIs via SO.

Answer (score 0):

On Java portion generate the image and convert to base64Image. Then directly embed base64image in HTML page and render that via jetty/HTTP server.